# Digitize a file showing spatial area using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, coordinates, contour

I have the following scanned image of an area which I want to digitize in terms of **coordinates** and **depths**, where depths are shown in terms of contour lines. The depths are shown in the above image by the number over the contour line. I would like to divide this image in terms of grids/pixels and get two data - representing it's (x, y) coordinates and depth - for every grid/pixel.

Is there some Matlab function or File Exchange in Matlab that can be used to perform this task than doing manually? I would like to perform this task faster than if it were to be done manually. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How are you plannimng to show depth? Different color for each contour maybe?

Comment: The depths are shown in the above image by the number over the contour line. I would like to divide this image in terms of several grids/pixels and get two data - representing it's (x, y) coordinates and depth - for every grid/pixel. 
I suppose what you are asking pertains to plotting?

Comment: I remember file that would trace the lines. But that would take you only half way. But on the other hand if you go into a paint program and do connect the lines - maybe even color the levels it would be trivial. How many of these maps do you need to process?